# Unable to extract to specific directory

Tags: shell, tar, sunos, zcat

I am trying to extract to file to specific directory but it doesn't produce result.

**Command:**

```
zcat /export/home/tceng/Desktop/temp/3.tar.Z | tar -xf - -C /export/home/tceng/Desktop/temp/TestExtractUtility/
```

if we remove value -C onwards in above command it produces result.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
zcat ... | ( cd /path/to/desired/directory; tar -xf - )
```